# How to write values of dictionary in numpy array to csv file instead of the full dictionary?

Tags: python, file, csv, numpy, dictionary

I'm trying to write a multidimensional `numpy` array to a `.csv` file.  This array includes words, numbers, and a dictionary.  When writing the file, my code prints the keys and values to the array.  However, I need only the values to be written.

My code can be seen as follows:

```
import numpy as np

lowercase_letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

words_array = np.genfromtxt('words_file.txt', dtype=str).reshape(300, 1)

lowercase_words = np.array([word[0].lower() for word in words_array])
words_array = np.append(words_array, lowercase_words.reshape(300, 1), axis=1)

def letter_frequency(word):
  letter_frequency = {}
for letter in lowercase_letters:
  letter_frequency[letter] = 0
for letter in word:
  letter_frequency[letter] += 1
return letter_frequency

vectorized_frequencies = np.vectorize(letter_frequency)
frequencies = vectorized_frequencies(lowercase_words)
words_array = np.append(words_array, frequencies.reshape(300, 1), axis=1)

word_length = np.vectorize(len)
word_lengths = word_length(words_array[:, :1])
words_array = np.append(words_array, word_lengths.reshape(300, 1), axis=1)

np.savetxt('rocko_bishop_project2.csv', words_array, delimiter=',', fmt='%s',
       header="original, lower, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,length")
```

After writing the finalized array to the csv file (also required, I can't export as a different file type), it prints the full dictionary, with keys and values:

```
Abject,abject,{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 0, 'e': 1, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 1, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 0, 's': 0, 't': 1, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0},6
```

However, I would like to to just have the values printed instead.

```
Abject,abject,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

The parameters of the project prevent me from importing `pandas`, or any other library other than `numpy`.

What is the best course of action?

Comment: Why not to save an array as numpy .npz file? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html

Comment: You need to show or explain the array better.  `numpy` arrays don't normally contain dictionaries.  My guess is that you need to convert the array to a list, and then use normal formatted Python file writes to write the desired data.

Comment: I've edited the question to offer more information. This is a weird assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Assume, for lack of further information, that your `array` is really a `list` like:

```
In [338]: alist = ['Abjure','abjure',{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 1, 'f
     ...: ': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 1, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 
     ...: 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 1, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 1, 'v': 0, 'w': 0
     ...: , 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}]
```

If it isn't a list, it must be a object dtype array, in which case `arr.tolist()` should produce the same list.

As first try, just print (with possible redirect to file), the elements:

```
In [341]: print(alist[:2], list(alist[2].values()))                             
['Abjure', 'abjure'] [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Here I use `values()` to get the dictionary values.

Now we can clean up the print (or file write).  This is plain Python.  No need to invoke `numpy` or any other package.

Expanding the sub lists:

```
In [343]: print(*alist[:2], *list(alist[2].values()))                           
Abjure abjure 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm not sure how well this will work.  I'll give it a shot though. I've edited the question to give more information on the situation.

Comment: `letter_frequency` is a dictionary.  Why not make it a list of values as I do?

Comment: `savetxt` is not fancy.  It iterates on the rows of the array.  For a row it does a formatted write.   `f.write(  fmt % tuple(row))` where `fmt` is made from your `%s`, replicated by the number of terms in `row`, e.g. ``['%s']*10)`